how to manage the rendering of custom tile overlays and google map in google map flutter
The current situation :
Whenever someone zoom in or zoom out the map render first and then the tile overlay renders, i want to show the screen only when the tiles have rendered , the tiles cannot be cached but they are made on client side. Can i show a loading status until the tiles are being generated?
using
google_maps_flutter: ^2.10.0
tileOverlays: {
              TileOverlay(
                tileOverlayId: TileOverlayId(tileID),
                tileProvider: CustomTileProvider(
                  Areas
                ),
                zIndex: 1,
              )
            },


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

When zooming in or out on the map in google_maps_flutter, the map renders first, and then the tile overlay renders. This creates a moment where only the base map is visible, resulting in a poor visual transition. I want to avoid this by showing a loading screen until the tile overlay is fully rendered, ensuring a seamless transition. @EsmaeilAhmadipour

Another problem is the getTile in custom tile overlay will make tile for each tile on the map so I don't know how many times the get tile will run
